# Upgrading multiple Access Databases Programmatically on 64-bit

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-migration, upsizing

I have an ASP.net application that is pulling data from Access databases using the *JET provider*.  I have recently pushed this application to production and learned that there is not a 64 bit provider for connecting to an Access database.

These Access database files I am retrieving from (about 30 of them) are being dynamically generated every day.  I am aware of the *Upsizing wizard* that Access provides, but it works very poorly and there is no way for me to automate this.

I have used the *SQL Server Import and Export Wizard* on a single Access database and it works quite well, but it seems to use the *Jet Provider* as well, so if there was a way to automate this, it wouldn't work on my 64 bit server.

Looking into an ODBC connection as a possible way to make a connection to an Access database, but this just seems to be a 'man in the middle' approach to my problem with a 32 bit provider like JET still being used.

After much research it seems as though there is not a 64 bit provider that can connect to Access.  So I ask, can I programmatically upgrade an Access database to a SQL database on a 64 bit environment?

Comment: I have already found this, if you expand details you will find it is not intended to: "4.To be used by a system service or server-side program where the code will run under a system account, or will deal with multiple users identities concurrently, or is highly reentrant and expects stateless behavior. Examples would include a program that is run from task scheduler when no user is logged in, or a program called from server-side web application such as ASP.NET, or a distributed component running under COM+ services."

Comment: I would love to give this a whirl, but I ask, why have they stated that it is not intended for such use?

Comment: Your comments are fine, I'm at the end of the road so any insight at this point is helpful.  I might give 64 bit ACE a try a little later and see what kind of response it gives me.  Thanks